I want to change the input of an optimization problem and store the solution of the optimization problem for every input
Python code for one input is given below:
from doopl.factory import create_opl_model

Damage_Nodes = [
(8,), (9,), (12,) , (16,) , (19,) , (23,) , (24,) , (27,) , (30,), 
]

model_path = "C:/Users/VVK/opl/Example/Example.mod"

with create_opl_model(model=model_path) as opl:

opl.set_input('Damage_line_Node',Damage_Nodes) 

# Generate the problem and solve it
opl.run()

# Get the names of post-processing tables
print("Table names are: " + str(opl.output_table_names))

# Get all the post-processing tables as dataframes.
for name, table in opl.report.items():  # iteritems is not necessary in Python 3
   print("Table: " + name)
for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
        print(t)

    # Nicer display
for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
        print(t[0], "node", t[1], "time",t[2],"restored")

Now I want to give different set of Damage_Nodes and run the OPL model for other input and store the result for that input. I don't want to change this input manually. I want to code this in Python.
Another sets of damage node is given below:
Damage_Nodes = [
(5,), (8,), (2,) , (26,) , (17,) , (37,) , (14,), 
]
Damage_Nodes = [
(15,), (7,), (22,) , (29,) , (1,) , (34,) , (11,),  (9,),
]

How can we code this in Python to modify the input for the OPL model and store the solution of the optimization problem for each input?
